# Making a circuit entirely with 4:1 MUX, 2-input OR gate and NOT gate

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer

I'm stuck on this question for half of a day. Let's say I have this function

[image]

That's everything I know about it. Now I must implement it using only 4:1 MUX, 2-input OR gate and NOT gate. I've tried to look at the truth table and create a circuit, but it uses a constant and AND gate, which is forbidden in my case.

[image]

Is there any convenient way to solve this problem, instead of trying to guess it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there. Your solution uses the mux to select rows of the K map and then you generate the correct function for each row.

If you instead use the mux to select columns of the K map — i.e., connect "y" and "z" to the select lines — then you can generate the function for each column: column zero is just "x" and column 1 is "w+x". In other words, the only other gate you need is the OR gate. The NOT must have been thrown in as a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to OR some ANDs. Reserve the OR for that.

And you need Y', so use the inverter for that.

Now  you need X, and YZ.

Can the 4:1 mux do that?

=================================

The MUX has 4 + 2 = 6 inputs. Draw a truth table.

Given the MUX has only ONE output pin, can the MUX generate X + YZ?

If not, then we need to reconsider.